# Javascript variable object keys

Tags: javascript, variables, object, key

I am attempting to add a variable key, with no luck.

Here's what I got so far:

```
mysql('translations',{
    check: 'element_id',
    element_id: element_id,
    {'lang-'+lang_id}: value
});
```

The variable key is the last line of the function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't use expressions for the identifiers in an object literal.

First create the object, then you can use dynamic names:

```
var obj = {
  check: 'element_id',
  element_id: element_id,
}

obj['lang-'+lang_id] = value;

mysql('translations', obj);
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing something like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var x = {
    check: 'element_id',
    element_id: element_id    
};
x['lang-'+lang_id] = value;

mysql('translations', x);
```