# JSON stringify object key does not use expressions

Tags: json, variables, key-value

I am getting the following values to put into my JSON stringify method. I will use it for AJAX. The `field_name` variable can vary.

```
value = input.val()
parent = input.parent()
userId = parent.data().userid
field_name = parent.data().field

$.ajax "/api/users/#{userId}",
  method: 'PATCH'
  contentType: 'application/json'
  dataType: 'json'
  data: JSON.stringify( {user:{field_name:value}})
  success: (data) =>
```

However, the keys in `{user:{field_name:value}}` do not express variables. Only the value of the k-v pair can express variables. How can I make the key `field_name` use variables to be flexible for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript variable object keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651803/javascript-variable-object-keys)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)